# AWS Code works in PHP 5.5.6 but not in PHP 5.3.1

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

Below code works in PHP version 5.5.6 and not in PHP 5.3.1.
When running this file, it shows an empty page.

```
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;

$bucket = 'report160316';
$keyname = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
// Instantiate the client.
$s3 = S3Client::factory([
    'key' =>$keyname,
    'secret' =>$secret,
]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [AWS SDK for PHP requirements page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/requirements.html) (emphasis mine):

> ## Minimum requirements
>
> ---
>
> - **PHP 5.3.3+** compiled with the cURL, JSON, and XML extensions
> - A recent version of cURL 7.16.2+ compiled with OpenSSL and zlib

So, your PHP version is simply not meeting the minimum requirements.

Comment: thank you..i have another server PHP 5.3.3 but cURL version is  7.15.5 AWS will work or not..????

Answer (score 0):

For PHP/5.3 you need to use array() instead of [].

i.e.

```
$s3 = S3Client::factory(array(
   'key' => $keyname,
   'secret' => $secret,
));
```